# Error reading from excel in c#

Tags: c#, excel

I have a code that is supposed to read from a excel document and tell me what is inside and I got a error. So, when I use the keyword "excel" the program should open a file dialog and let me select a excel document and after it should tell me what is inside. Here's the code

```
                  case "excel":
                if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application _excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                    _excelApp.Visible = true;

                    string fileName = @"C:\Users\N.Horatiu\Desktop\a.docx\\";

                    Workbook workbook = _excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

                    Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];

                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelRange = worksheet.UsedRange;

                    object[,] valueArray = (object[,])excelRange.get_Value(
                                XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);

                    for (int row = 1; row <= worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count; ++row)
                    {
                        for (int col = 1; col <= worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count; ++col)
                        {
                            ss.SpeakAsync(valueArray[row, col].ToString());
                        }
                    }

                    workbook.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);

                    _excelApp.Quit();
                    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_excelApp);
                }
                break;
```

And here's the error  that I get after I select the document : [image: error]

Comment: It's pretty obvious if you look at the exception.  Does that look like a valid file path to you?

Comment: That is an ordinary "File Not Found" error.

Comment: How do you expect to open a Word document as an Excel sheet anyway?

Comment: In any case, if you want to open an *Excel* file use the Open XML SDK or a library like EPPlus, don't use interop to open the entire application. Saves you a few Gigabytes of RAM

Comment: A few... Gigabytes?  I doubt Excel is that big of a pig.

Comment: @RobertHarvey depends on how large the sheet is. The exaggeration is no worse than using Excel to read a couple of fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is being treated as a folder due to the blackslashes at the end of the file name.

Remove these blackslashes and retry

```
string fileName = @"C:\Users\N.Horatiu\Desktop\a.xlsx";
```

Comment: Didn't downvote yet but did you check the extension?